# Get unique together constraint name in db in Django

Tags: django, unique-constraint

How can I get the name of a unique together constraint in Django?

It seems to be generated quite randomly to e.g. `book_membership_collection_id_order_c52e778f_uniq`, and I need to programatically get this name to do something with `RunSQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it was possible via

```
connection.schema_editor()._constraint_names(MYModel, ['col1', 'col2'], unique=True)
```